# Пустой экран при запуске вместо окошка с вводом текста и клавиатуры - класс Text(С++, Cocos2d-x)

Tags: c++, cocos2d

Добрый вечер!Я работаю в visual studio 2015, используя cocos2d-x. У меня возникла странная проблема. При запуске кода у меня появляется черный экран вместо экрана с клавиатурой и окошечка с вводом текста.
Вот код:

```
auto size = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
auto textField = ui::TextField::create("Enter your name", "Arial", 30);
textField->setPosition(Vec2(size.width / 2, size.height*0.75f));
this->addChild(textField);
textField->addEventListener([](Ref* sender, ui::TextField::EventType type) {
    auto textField = dynamic_cast<ui::TextField*>(sender);
    switch (type) {
    case ui::TextField::EventType::ATTACH_WITH_IME:
        CCLOG("displayed Keyboard");
        break;
    case ui::TextField::EventType::DETACH_WITH_IME:
        CCLOG("dismissed keyboard");
    case ui::TextField::EventType::INSERT_TEXT:
        CCLOG("inserted text : %s",
            textField->getString().c_str());
        break;
    case ui::TextField::EventType::DELETE_BACKWARD:
        CCLOG("deleted backward");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
});
```

Должно получится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А получается пустой экран:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На основании чего Вы решили, что результат должен быть как на рисунке? Если Вы пишете программу по какому-то руководству, приведите соответствующие ссылки.

Comment: Я пользуюсь книгой Cocos2d-x Cookbook

Comment: Будет лучше, если Вы укажите это в теле вопроса путём его редактирования. А так же добавите ISBN книги и номера страниц с описанием, возможно приведёте цитаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. У меня нет 50 реп. чтобы оставить коммент, придется написать это как ответ.
У вас на верхнем скриншоте картинка с клавиатурой из iOS при этом, свой пример вы запускаете как classic win32 app (старое, не metro-приложение). 
В данном случае экранной клавиатуры не будет, хотя движок будет эмулировать ее появление изменяя размер отображаемой области(тут не уверен на 100% потому что в нашем случае клавиатура показывается поверх вьюпорта, зависит от реализации).

в win32 ввод идет просто с клавиатуры, либо через модальное окно с полем ввода.